# dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated is deprecated first deprecated in ios 6

Tags: iphone

I have just updated iOS 6, and run my old code, which is created in iOS 4.3. They give me number of warnings in my application.

I used `presentModelViewController:` and then I dismiss it, but it gave me warning

> dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated first deprecated in iOS 6.

Why they show warning to that code? Here is the code:

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This line gets yellow and show the error. Please give me guideline to remove the warning.

Comment: read the UIViewController docs, they will tell you what to use instead

Comment: give code of where you create `picker` ViewController and how :)

Answer (score 60):

Now in ios 6 You can use

```
[[Picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Instead of

```
[[Picker parentViewControl] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Instead of

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

You should only get the deprecation warning if your deployment target is set to iOS 6. So I would check your deployment target, which is probably set to the Xcode default. Once you change this to 4.3 the deprecation warnings should disappear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion`, from the [iOS Developer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated%3acompletion%3a) docs

> dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
>
> Dismisses the view controller that was presented by the receiver.
>   - (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion Parameters
>
> flag
>
> ```
> Pass YES to animate the transition. completion
>
> A block called after the view controller has been dismissed.
> ```
>
> Discussion
>
> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the
>   presenting view controller.
>
> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a
>   stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view
>   controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view
>   controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack.
>   When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated
>   fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the
>   stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition
>   style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers
>   lower in the stack.
>
> If you want to retain a reference to the receiver’s presented view
>   controller, get the value in the presentedViewController property
>   before calling this method.
>
> The completion handler is called after the viewDidDisappear: method is
>   called on the presented view controller. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
> ```

Comment: thanks for  guidence,.. its works well. can i ask you one question? why their use "completion:(void (^)(void))completion",

Comment: is "a block called after the view controller has been dismissed"